# Setting the visible region in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I can get the visible region based on the screen coordinates using

```
googlemap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()
```

But I can’t figure out how to set the visible region so that the map container only shows my bounding box

I can create a bounding box but the map still shows the area around the box, it just stops the user from panning away from the defined area

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

This is a diagram of what I need. The image on the right shows the current container of the Google map with the desired bounding box. When I create the bounding box, I want to be able to set the entire view of the google map container to only show this area like shown in the left image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @NoumanCh unfortunately not what I am looking for, see updated question for image and more detailed description

Comment: Have you tried the CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds - that still is limited by zoom level precision though.  What is interesting about your diagrams is that you seem to have rotated the box as well - is this intentional (which would require changing the camera's bearing as well)?

Comment: @Andy thanks for the pointer on the bearing! sometimes I may need to rotate the box depending on the orientation of the box compared to the position of the top left of the container.....do you have any ideas on calculating the bearing required, I tried calculating based on the top left position of the container and a corner point on the box but its still off?

Comment: First (a) convert lat/lng box to x/y plane (b) compute relative rotation (to screen plane) by using tan-1 (inverse tan) on rotation point and adjacent point and (c) add to current screen/map bearing +/- 90.  This is the general case but is easier if you can always assume the box is aligned in which case rotation is simply 90.  Too bad they closed the question - they always are quick to do so - or I'd expand in greater detail.

Comment: @Andy awesome thanks, I'll implement your suggestion. Pitty them closing the question alright, I thought it was explained well enough to show its not a duplicate of that other question